# How to use python boto3 inside of an AWS CodeBuild build?

Tags: aws-codebuild

I need to send SNS notifications directly from inside my CodeBuild script, but I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

Is it possible to fix? Or is the CodeBuild environment just too restrictive to allow this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

CodeBuild curated images for Python don't have boto3 installed. You could use `pip install boto3` to install this module during the build by specifying this command in the buildspec.yml. For example, if your python file is `main.py`, you buildspec.yml should look like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    - pip install boto3
    - [other install commands if needed]
  build:
    - python main.py
```